# MySQL falsely ignoring Null values

Tags: mysql, null

I am trying to run a fairly straightforward query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT COLUMN1 IN ('A','B')
```

I am expecting this to return the rows where `COLUMN1` is `NULL`, however, in addition to getting rid of anything that is `A` and `B` it also removes any `NULL` values in COLUMN1 and I don't get the logic. Very much new to this so would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `WHERE column1 IS NULL`?

Comment: Because there are more values in it. I just don't want ```A``` and ```B```, but anything else, which is ```NULL``` and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` has some unexpected behaviors. Probably the most confusing is that while it acts like `FALSE` when used as a condition, it doesn't act like it when used as a sub-expression of a condition. The value of most expressions that include `NULL` is `NULL` (the most obvious exceptions are that `NULL IS NULL` and `NULL IS NOT NULL` are `TRUE` and `FALSE`).

So the value of `NULL IN ('A', 'B')` is `NULL`, not `FALSE`.

And the value of `NOT NULL` is `NULL`, not `TRUE`.

So when `COLUMN1` is `NULL`, the value of `NOT COLUMN1 IN ('A', 'B')` is `NULL`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

You have to test for `NULL` explicitly.

```
WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column1 NOT IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: That didnt do the trick unfortunately, still getting the same problem where NULL values in COLUMN1 are omitted

Comment: Sorry, when I was adding that I forgot what your goal was.